# How can I run an executable file without the "./" using a MakeFile?

Tags: linux, shell, unix, command-line, makefile

I want to run my program with an executable without the "./"

For example lets say I have the makefile:

```
 all: RUN

 RUN: main.o

       gcc -0 RUN main.o

 main.o: main.c

      gcc -c main.c
```

So in order to run the program normally I would say in the terminal "make" then put "./RUN" to invoke the program.

But I would just like to say in the terminal "make" then "RUN" to invoke the program.

So to conclude I would just like to say >RUN instead of >./RUN inside the terminal. Is there any command I can use to do this inside the Makefile?

When I just put "RUN" in the terminal it just says command not found.

Comment: What happens if you type `RUN` instead of `./RUN`?  That is, I don't understand what the problem is.

Comment: [Why do I need to type `./` before executing a program in the current directory?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/320632/why-do-i-need-to-type-before-executing-a-program-in-the-current-directory)

Comment: It says RUN: command not found

Comment: You don't want to use `./`. Do it anyway.

Comment: Why not use `PWD` and use `$(PWD)/RUN` in your recipe? The prefix can be extended to allow you to build out-of-tree, too. Are you using Posix Make of a full featured make, like GNU Make?

Answer (score 3):

It is a matter of [$PATH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_%28variable%29), which is imported by `make` from your [environment](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Environment.html).

You might set it in your `Makefile`, perhaps with

```
export PATH=$(PATH):.
```

or

```
export PATH:=$(shell echo $$PATH:.)
```

but **I don't recommend doing that** (it could be a security hole).

I recommend on the contrary using *explicitly* `./RUN` in your `Makefile`, which is much more readable and less error-prone (what would happen if you got a `RUN` program *somewhere else* in your `PATH` ?).

BTW, you'll better read [more](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/index.html) about `make`, run once `make -p` to understand the builtin rules known to `make`, and have

```
CC= gcc
CFLAGS+= -Wall -g
```

<sup>(because you really want all warnings & debug info)</sup>

and simply

```
main.o: main.c
```

(without recipes in that rule) in your `Makefile`

Comment: I would hope that the `export PATH=$(PATH):.` is near the top of everyone's DO-NOT-DO list. It is a security hole indeed. Not sure if the most worrying thing is a post suggesting doing it (even with a warning that might come too late for the attention span of some SO users) or the upvotes (possibly from SO users with an attention span of less than 6 lines).

Comment: @ComeRaczy: The OP is asking to have `.` in his `PATH`. Yes, it is a bad idea and a security hole, but he is asking that!

Comment: the OP actually asked how to run a program with an executable without the "./". There are safer ways to achieve that than adding "." to the path. One example would be an alias. A generic alias like `alias RUN=./RUN` would be safer than '.' in the path. A path-specific alias like `alias RUN='if  [ $PWD = /path/to -a -e /path/to/RUN ] ; then /path/to/RUN ; else RUN ; fi'` would have the added benefit of restricting the behavior to just one specific directory and one specific program when it exists, otherwise keeping the default behavior

Comment: You can't define aliases in a `Makefile` because the shell there is non-interactive.

Comment: You are absolutely right. My comment was in the context of the OP question who wants _to say **in the terminal** "make" then "RUN"_

Answer (score 0):

change your makefile to

```
    all: RUN

    RUN: main.o

        gcc -o RUN main.o && ./RUN

    main.o: main.c

        gcc -c main.c
```

just put ./filename in your makefile

Comment: Hmmm... The OP states they don't want to use `"./"`.